# How to remove intermediate pages during Django all auth Facebook login?

Tags: django, facebook-login, django-allauth

I am using Django all-auth to enable Google & Facebook social logins to my application. The flow is working fine but there are two unnecessary screens in the flow. The config is as follows:

```
ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION = env.bool("DJANGO_ACCOUNT_ALLOW_REGISTRATION", True)
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "project.users.adapters.AccountAdapter"
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = "project.users.adapters.SocialAccountAdapter"

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    "google": {
        "SCOPE": [
            "profile",
            "email",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl",
        ],
        "AUTH_PARAMS": {
            "access_type": "offline",
        },
    },

    "facebook":
        {
        'METHOD': 'oauth2',
        'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'INIT_PARAMS': {'cookie': True},
        'FIELDS': [
            'id',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'middle_name',
            'name',
            'name_format',
            'picture',
            'short_name'
        ],
        'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
        'LOCALE_FUNC': lambda request: 'en_US',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
        'VERSION': 'v7.0',
        },
}
```

This is what I see after clicking on Google/Facebook login button:
[image: Confirmation Screen on choosing Social login]

And this comes up after completing Facebook login:
[image: SignUp Email Form After Facebook OAuth]

I don't want any of these two intermediate screens, and tried modifying configuration as well. But these screens are not mentioned in the Django All-Auth docs so what am I missing?

Answer (score 6):

The [docs](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html) don't recommend using `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True` for security reasons. Use a form instead to send a `POST` request:

```
<form action="{% provider_login_url 'facebook' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <button type="submit">Continue with Facebook</button>
</form>
```

You also need to set `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP = True` in `settings.py` (this is the default value).

Comment: Worked very well for me!. Just had to adapt from `<a>..` to `<button>` inside a form. `SOCIALACCOUNT_AUTO_SIGNUP` is True by default. Also, ones should not forget about the `{% csrf_token %}`

Comment: For those looking for the specific security reasons of why to not use `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True`, see the [Changelog for django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/main/ChangeLog.rst#security-notice-3) and [Google's blog post about open redirect abuse](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2009/01/open-redirect-urls-is-your-site-being).

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET` to TRUE.

https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#backwards-incompatible-changes-1

Answer (score 0):

Open your setting.py file of django project
and add following line in bottom of the file

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
```